# validateForm.validate is not a function в чем проблем?

Tags: php, jquery

Пытаюсь воспользоваться планигином .validation. Делаю все по инструкции. Попробовал подключать скриптом и через npm, но ошибка остается. В чем может быть дело?

main.php

```
<script src='/../../web/index.js' type="module"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
$(document).on('click', '.send', function() {
    // alert("232");
    var validateForm = $(document).find('#contacsform');
    validateForm.validate({
        rules: {
            fromPerson: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            fromPlace: {
                required: true,                
                minlength: 5
            },
            toPerson:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            toPlace:{
                required: true,                
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            fromPerson: {
                required: "Введите Ваше Имя",
                minlength: "Имя должно быть более 2-х символов"
                
            }            
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {                
            form.submit();
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {                 
            var item = element.parents('.item');
            item.append(error);
        }
    });
 
    validateForm.submit();
});
```

Это моя HTML форма, прописанная внутри index.php
Я использую Yii php, пока довольно плохо разобрался со структурой файлов и папок тут

```
<form class = "post" id="contacsform"> 
    <div class = "item">
        <span class = "from-person">От кого</span>
        <input type = "text" name = "fromPerson"></input>

        <span class = "from-place">От куда</span>
        <input type = "text" name = "fromPlace"></input>
    </div>

    <div class = "item">
        <span class = "to-person">Кому</span>
        <input type = "text" name = "toPerson"></input>


        <span class = "to-place">Куда</span>
        <input type = "text" name = "toPlace"></input>
    </div>

    <span class = "email">email</span>
    <input type = "email" name = "email"> </input>
    <button type="button" class="send">Скачать</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш html

Comment: @СергейМишин Отредактировал вопрос